# Using Ant variable within embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, ant

I am working on some Ant Script and also using ant-contrib.jar file in my script.
My ant script contents following code block which is not working as per my requirements.

```
<if>
            <equals arg1="${require.html}" arg2="1"/>
            <then>
                <script language="javascript">
                <![CDATA[                       
                    println("<h3>Selected Project Directory: ${project.dir}</h3>");
                    println("<h3>Generated reports are at the location ${dir.report}</h3>");
                ]]>
                </script>
            </then>
        </if>
```

I am trying to use ${project.dir} variable in Embedded JavaScript with Ant Script. Here using script i am trying to generate html file.
but the output displayed on the browser is as under:

```
Selected Project Directory: ${project.dir}
Generated reports are at the location ${dir.report}
```

Expected output:

```
Selected Project Directory: C:\Project
Generated reports are at the location C:\Report
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs say](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) as long as the property is a valid JavaScript identifier then you can reference it directly as if it was a var in scope. Since yours contain a dot you can't do that, but you can still access them this way:

`println("<h3>Selected Project Directory: " + project.getProperty("project.dir") + "</h3>");`